# External Javascript Script Never Being Called

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, getelementbyid

I am trying to learn javascript with this simple exercise and I seemed to be stumped. I need to make a simple calculation when a quantity is put in 3 separate text boxes and call my function to calculate it but no number is returned. So a quantity is put into each box,  here is my attempt:

```js
function sum2()
{
      var one = document.getElementById("book_1").value;
      var two = document.getElementById("book_2").value;
      var three = document.getElementById("book_3").value;

      if ((one == "")||(two == "")||(three == ""))
      {
        alert ('Error', 'values missing');
      }
      else
      {
         var sum1 = one * 19.99;
         var sum2 = two * 86.00;
         var sum3 = three * 55.00;
         var sum = sum1 + sum2 + sum3;

         document.getElementById('output').value = sum;
         document.write(sum);
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Work</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ex4.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="container">
     <h2>Order Books Online</h2>
     <form action="" method="post" id=”frm”>
       <fieldset>
       <table border="0">
         <tr>
           <th>Book</th>
           <th>Quantity</th>
           <th>Price</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Basics of C++</td>
           <td><input type="text" size="3" id="book_1" /></td>
           <td>$19.99</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Program Development in Perl</td>
           <td><input type="text" size="3" id="book_2" /></td>
           <td>$86.00</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Advanced JavaScript</td>
           <td><input type="text" size="3" id="book_3" /></td>
           <td>$55.00</td>
         </tr>
       </table>
       <br /><br />
       <input type="submit" onclick="return sum2()" value="Place Order" id="sub" />
       </fieldset>
      </form>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think I have the right code but maybe just missing something. My external javascript file is called ex4.js and is in the same folder as the html file. My function is right and I believe I am calling it correctly so I have no idea where I am going wrong with this and just want the sum to be returned!!

Comment: file is ex.js or ex4.js ?

Comment: If the file is called `ex.js` then you're getting an error on your browser console telling you that the file `ex4.js` wasn't found.  Always at least look at the browser console.

Comment: @lucyb: Still check the browser console.  You've defined one function called `sum2`, but call two functions (`sum()` and `sum2()`).  And when you call `sum2()` there are no values available for input.  Use your browser's debugger, step through the code as it executes, you can see its exact behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the function immediately when the page loads:

```
<script>
    document.write(sum2());
</script>
```

At that time, these elements have no values:

```
var one = document.getElementById("book_1").value;
var two = document.getElementById("book_2").value;
var three = document.getElementById("book_3").value;
```

Because the page is just loading, the user hasn't input any values yet.

---

You also attempt to call a function which doesn't exist here:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="sum()" value="Place Order" id="sub" />
```

That's where you should be calling the function you have:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="sum2()" value="Place Order" id="sub" />
```

---

You also have a syntax error here:

```
alert (Error, values missing);
```

Strings are supposed to have quotes around them:

```
alert ('Error', 'values missing');
```

---

You're also not *doing anything* with the result of the function:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="sum2()" value="Place Order" id="sub" />
```

If this function is handling the click event, then you should do two things:

- Cancel the event so the form doesn't post
- In the function, output the value to the page

Something like this:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return sum2()" value="Place Order" id="sub" />
```

Then in the function you would return `false` after using your value:

```
document.getElementById('output').value = sum;
return false;
```

---

As a side note, you should also use the `var` keyword when declaring variables.  That way they stay in local scope instead of `window` scope:

```
var sum1 = one * 19.99;
var sum2 = two * 86.00;
var sum3 = three * 55.00;
var sum = sum1 + sum2 + sum3;
```

Additionally, this is a *great* opportunity to familiarize yourself with the developer tools in your browser.  You can monitor network requests (to ensure the external resources are even loaded in the first place), read error messages (when the browser is *trying* to tell you the problem), and place debugging breakpoints in your code to step through and see what's happening as it executes.

Debugging is *always* better than guessing.

Comment: if I return false, isn't nothing ever going to be returned? I want to return the sum, a value

Comment: @lucyb: Returning `false` in this case stops the form submit event from happening, since you're clicking a `submit` button on a `form`, which by default will reload the page and reset everything you're doing.  Why do you want to return the value anyway?  Where in your code are you doing anything with the returned value?  (Hint: Nowhere)

Comment: when I debug, IE skips over my alert box and nothing happens (theres no alert message)

Comment: @lucyb: Did you fix the syntax errors?  Is there an error on the console?  When it "skips" that line, what specifically *does* it do?

Comment: There is not error in the console, debugging simply hovers over it and goes to the next line despite not inputting any numbers into the field. All synxtax errors that you suggested have been fixed

Comment: @lucyb: What are the runtime values?  Maybe they're not `null`?

Comment: I want to return sum instead of false, by clicking on the button the computation will be take place, and I want sum to be returned in text underneath the place order box. I am doing this in the function portion of my code and I am calling the function in the index form with the onclick portion.

Comment: @lucyb: Then you're going to need a second function which calls this function.  For example, let's call it `printSum`.  The button would call `printSum()`, which would call `sum2()` and put the result on the page, and then would return `false`.  As you've currently structured the code, returning the value makes no sense because the code which calls the function doesn't use that returned value.

Comment: I dont understand why I would need a second function to call the first. The first should be able to make a calculation based off the 3 inputs and return a  sum with the button is clicked, should it not be capable of this? I dont want the result to return false, I need sum, and a second function is not making sense to me here, sorry.

Comment: @lucyb: When your one function returns the result, what happens to that returned value?  Again, as before, *where* do you use that value?  The only attempt you've made to use it is in a `document.write()` which doesn't work because it executes before the values have been entered.  So, aside from that, in the `input` tag, *how is that value used*?  I don't really know how else to explain this.  When a function returns a value, the code which calls that function would have the responsibility of using that value.  *Your code doesn't do that*.

Comment: I am still lost and unsure how to proceed, have tried many different ways and have spent the past day and a half looking for an answer.  Heres a function I made, I am baffled by this, and do not know where I am supposed to use submit. I'm calling the first function using the submit value and for onclick it has now changed to onclick=printSum()                                                                               function printSum(submit)
{
  return sum2();
}

Comment: @lucyb: That function doesn't do what I described in my comment above.  This `printSum` function should write the value to an element on the page and return `false`.  All you have here is a pass-through function that doesn't itself actually do anything, so it doesn't change the problem you have in any way.

Comment: I am still lost, if you know the solution and it is a simple one, please present it, because I'm sure it is just a few lines of code- I cannot waste any further time, and I am unaware how to use the calling of the function through another function in javascript, thanks.

Comment: @lucyb: I've already posted a detailed answer to the question that was asked.  I'm afraid Stack Overflow isn't the right venue for direct one-on-one tutoring services.  We can answer specific questions, but a comment thread on a website is not a means to learn how to program or how to construct logical operations.  If you can put together another complete question where you present the code you're using and ask something about it, I encourage you to post it as a new question.